# Burninate the [raw] meta-tag

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Prior to an intervention, the [raw](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/raw) tag was used for two different things:

- Questions involving the camera RAW format. All of these questions that weren't closed were retagged with the  [camera-raw](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/camera-raw) tag.
- Questions involving "raw" (uninitialized) hard disks, thumb drives, etc.

Since the first use has been eliminated*, the [raw](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/raw) tag is now restricted to the second use, thus making it a clear [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Please burninate the [raw](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/raw) meta-tag now that it's been disambiguated.
 <sub>* - There are still [two](https://superuser.com/questions/9614/free-raw-file-converter-editor) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/82860/best-software-to-edit-canon-raw-files-cr2) that relate to camera RAW, but they've been closed as off-topic/not constructive because they solicit software recommendations.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the tags are gone.

*Poof.*